# android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView Menu item touch taking more space

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I Created the BottomNavigationView with below xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Selected item taking more space than original view as below. Any suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: If you mean the text getting bigger, it is the default behaviour. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I was taking about below circle area when i touch the Keypad. usually it should not this much area when i select the item.